# Ionic Angular 5. Star rating system

Tags: ionic-framework, angular5, rating

I am building an app on ionic. I have some numbers available for rating/reviews. I want to show/convert them as stars and present it in my UI. Is there any library available for this in Angular 5?

Thanks

Comment: I'd never seen any library to do it. But, i already created some components, where i just use 'ngFor' between 1 and 5 to show stars. Maybe you can create something in the same way.

Comment: https://github.com/stove654/ionicRate

Comment: I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-star-rating  and it worked quite well for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this lib in a app to do horizontal rating, but have stars too:
https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-bar-rating